# scala / lift example of form processing

Tags: scala, lift

Can I get a simple example of a Lift form submission and processor? I've seen the Lift hello world, which was pretty trivial and didn't really give a flavor for how it works. I'm coming from a spring MVC background, but I have some FP experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a whole chapter on Forms in ExploringLift (chapter 4 covers the fundamentals). You can download a pdf from [here](http://groups.google.com/group/the-lift-book)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know an open source version of the book was available.